# How to implement a symbolic execution engine for a particular language?

Tags: testing, symbolic-execution

I'm considering using symbolic execution to test the robustness of programs written in a particular language such as java. I've read some papers introducing the basic concepts of symbolic execution. But I'm not clear about how to get it started.

For example, how can I generate the constraint conditions from a concrete input?
So any one can give me some advice on the basics of the implementation of symbolic execution? Furthermore, what about concolic execution(concrete + symbolic) ?

Answer (score -1):

> how can I generate the constraint conditions from a concrete input?

using symbolic or concolic execution

> So any one can give me some advice on the basics of the implementation
>   of symbolic execution?

My advice is the same as Ziming Zhao: use an existent symbolic execution tool. Do not attempt to implement your own, it would be too hard and time-consuming.

Here are the most popular projects (a more complete list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution)):

Java: [JPF + Symbolic Pathfinder](http://babelfish.arc.nasa.gov/trac/jpf/wiki/projects/jpf-symbc), [JCute](https://github.com/osl/jcute).

C and C++: [KLEE](https://klee.github.io/), [Kite](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/isd/Projects/Kite/)